# Swing GUI listeners without AWT

Tags: java, swing, awt, listener, layout-manager

I am a starting Java developer, learning just from internet tutorials. I am learning full-screen GUI applications. I was told yesterday that I shouldn't use AWT in my programs because it is outdated. I already know about light and heavyweight components, the main problem is the mouse and keyboard listeners.
Why is AWT outdated?

How to make a program without AWT (adding listeners to a `JComponent` etc)? What kind of Swing things can replace the AWT?

Comment: I have never heard of listeners other than AWT. Would be nice to know it myself.

Comment: @Nideo:  Feast your 'ears' on the 20+ listeners in the [`javax.swing.event` package](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/package-summary.html). ;)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You're mis-interpreting the information given to you. You should avoid using Swing components with AWT **components**. It's OK to use Swing with the AWT listener structure, layout managers, etc. and in fact it's impossible not to.

Answer (score 36):

There have been some good answers, but I would like to cover a slightly different aspect.  Things that Swing provides beyond AWT.

### Components

Swing supports styled documents in `JEditorPane` & `JTextPane` & to a limited extent using HTML in some other `JComponents`.  AWT does not support styled documents in any component.

AWT provides no tree based structure like `JTree`, no tabular structure such as `JTable`, no version of `JToolBar`.

[image]

AWT has no equivalent (that I can find or recall) for `JColorChooser` & none for the simple utility class - `JOptionPane`.

[image]

### Listeners

As mentioned in a comment, see the 20+ extra/alternate listeners in the `javax.swing.event` package.

### Pluggable Look & Feel

Swing components can be set to a particular look & feel at run-time, including a native PLAF.

[image]

See the screen shots on the [Nested Layout Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271) for some more samples.

### Layouts

In addition to the plethora of AWT layouts, Swing provides:

1. `BoxLayout`
2. `GroupLayout`
3. `OverlayLayout`
4. `ScrollPaneLayout`
5. `SpringLayout`
6. `ViewportLayout`

### Other

- Key Bindings.  See [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for details.
- [`UndoManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html) for undo/redo ability in editable documents.
- Inbuilt [double buffering](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#db) to avoid flicker on repaint.
- [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for responsive GUIs.

---

There is probably a lot more I missed in that brief description, but the bottom line is that Swing is an altogether newer and more enabled GUI toolkit.

*Swing both builds on, **and** relies heavily on, classes in the AWT.*

Answer (score 7):

Java's Swing takes ActionListeners, which are part of the AWT package.  If you wish to use swing, you must use some form of an AWT ActionListener.  That is just the way things are.  I don't suggest using Java at all for complex guis, but nor would I say that AWT is outdated, as there is no direct replacement.  Thus, just go ahead and use AWT.

As an alternative, you could look into JOGL, but that's more if you are trying to create something game-oriented.

Answer (score 2):

This is a small example which can demonstrate, the use of **javax.swing.Action** package
you should also refer to java doc for **javax.swing.event** package i think you are finding that . . .

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

class SysOutHelloAction extends AbstractAction {
    private static final Icon printIcon = new ImageIcon("Print.gif");

    SysOutHelloAction() {
        super("Print", printIcon);
        putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Hello, World");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}

public class SwingActionTester {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Action Sample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final Action printAction = new SysOutHelloAction();
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("File");
        menuBar.add(menu);
        menu.add(new JMenuItem(printAction));
        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
        toolbar.add(new JButton(printAction));
        JButton enableButton = new JButton("Enable");
        ActionListener enableActionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                printAction.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
        enableButton.addActionListener(enableActionListener);
        JButton disableButton = new JButton("Disable");
        ActionListener disableActionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                printAction.setEnabled(false);
            }
        };
        disableButton.addActionListener(disableActionListener);
        JButton relabelButton = new JButton("Relabel");
        ActionListener relabelActionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                printAction.putValue(Action.NAME, "Changed Action Value");
            }
        };
        relabelButton.addActionListener(relabelActionListener);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(enableButton);
        buttonPanel.add(disableButton);
        buttonPanel.add(relabelButton);
        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        frame.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right.  Both Java AWT and Java Spring are obsolete.  Use JavaFX instead.
And, as a commentary, I am frustrated with Java, that it was supposed to be "write once run everywhere", when now it turns out to be "must keep rewriting your app every three months" because new Java releases break previous code, and new packages replace the old.